# Can Kivy TextInput render colored fonts?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I've downloaded the emoji-One font (for Apple, the android ttf file doesn't seem to be working, even though I'm on Windows 7) and found out that it does not contain anything but emojis. That's fine by me. I've put it as a font for a TextInput and right when I typed a letter, my app crashed with a following log:

```
 Exception ignored in: 'kivy.graphics.texture.Texture.allocate'
 Exception: Unable to allocate memory for texture (size is -564608384)
```

which seems pretty odd to me, I'd expect it to put boxes instead of crashing. But the letters weren't intended to be in this font, fine. But the same thing happened when I tried typing the smile face "☺", which is in the font (I checked with FontForge, etc.). All of that confuses me. Perhaps Kivy does not support colored fonts? And if that's the case, what would be the best way to include emoji in the `TextInput`? There are `.png` files, `.svg` files and `.ttf` fonts. The `svgs` caused me some trouble to put into a font so I'd want to stay away from them.
I'm using Python 3.4, Kivy version 1.9.1
**EDIT**: The code is as simple as just a single `TextInput`:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

class Test(App):
    def build(self):
        return TextInput(font_name = "emojione-apple.ttf",
                         font_size = 1)

Test().run()
```

The font size doesn't matter, as it shows the cursor as wide as the height of a `TextInput`. You can get the font from the official GitHub repo. Direct link [here](https://github.com/emojione/emojione/raw/2.2.7/assets/fonts/emojione-apple.ttf).

Comment: Show us the code, it's impossible to tell what's going wrong without looking at the code for this part. Some where you are trying to create a texture that is too big for the memory. Where ...maybe the font_size is too big?... need to look at code.

Comment: @qua-non Here is the code. There isn't really anything here that I could've messed up, so I expect the issue to be on Kivy's side

Comment: Have you tried smaller file? Something that's not 30+MB? Also, I get rectangles, no memory error, therefore try something smaller first maybe? Anyway, I get rectangles for all of the symbols: A-Za-z0-9, even "" so I don't really know what to expect.

Comment: The weird thing is that I get rectangles even with [AndroidEmoji.ttf](https://github.com/delight-im/Emoji/raw/master/Android/assets/fonts/AndroidEmoji.ttf), which is small enough. I tried to input emoji there even with windows virtual keyboard, but no change. "☺" puts an empty character(like a `<space>`, not the rectangles). Kivy-master, py2.7. However, in AndroidEmoji.ttf I get that smiley face, so..... it works, but I'm not sure what exactly it displays as I don't have Forge installed.